# Another useless tag: [pages]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

[pages](/questions/tagged/pages) is used on 229 questions on Stackoverflow, and doesn't seem to add much to any of them. It's the lone tag on 2 questions, which would need to be retagged to some other vague Web-ish tag (or closed and deleted, since they're not very good questions to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]